# CSS border gradually appearing further away from associated ID

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a basic solar system using just CSS and I'm not sure where I've messed up that the border radius appears (e.g. their orbit path) appears just slightly away from there the planet is, and this increases further out (so the outer planets aren't even close to where the "ring" for their orbital path is appearing).

JSFiddle for all the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/7ebn3jkz/14/

Here's the HTML (still missing Neptune but wanted to fix this first):

```
 <div id ="universe">
        <!-- Sun -->
        <div id="sun">
        </div>
        <!-- Mercury -->
        <div id="mercury-orbit">
        <div id="mercury"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Venus -->
        <div id="venus-orbit">
        <div id="venus"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Earth -->
        <div id="earth-orbit">
        <div id="earth"></div>
        </div>

         <!-- Moon -->
        <div id="moon-orbit">
        <div id="moon"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Mars -->
        <div id="mars-orbit">
        <div id="mars"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Jupiter -->
        <div id="jupiter-orbit">
        <div id="jupiter"></div>
        </div>

       <!-- Saturn -->
        <div id="saturn-orbit">
        <div id="saturn"></div><div id ="saturn-rings"></div>
        </div>

       <!--Uranus -->
       <div id="uranus-orbit">
       <div id="uranus"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

And here's an example of the CSS for a planet

```
#mercury {
    position: absolute;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #919191; 
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #919191 0%, #7c7c7c 53%); 
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #919191 0%,#7c7c7c 53%); 
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #919191 0%,#7c7c7c 53%); 
}
```

And for its orbit

```
*/
#mercury-orbit {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 110px;
 height: 110px;
 margin-top: -55px;
 margin-left: -55px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: white;
 border radius: 50%;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-border-radius: 50%;
   -webkit-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
          animation: spin-right 5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin-right {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the 50% border-radius on each planets div to 0 just for testing purposes, you'll see exactly what the planet div is doing inside it and why it's placing where it is. It's doing what it should be, you just need to offset the alignment of each planet inside the rotation.

To fix this, add the code below. Don't forget to add the prefixes as required. You'll also need to adjust the code for the rings around Saturn.

```
#universe > div > div {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ebn3jkz/15/